# How can we determine the group which initiated SignalR extended method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, signalr

I have created a Javascript `function` to make SignalR even more magical:

```
//Initializable
function Initializable(params) {
    this.initialize = function (key, def, private) {
        if (def !== undefined) {
            (!!private ? params : this)[key] = (params[key] !== undefined) ? params[key] : def;
        }
    };
}
/*SignalR Updater*/
function SignalRUpdater(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);
    var self = this;
    this.initialize("RawHubs", [], true);
    this.initialize("RawGroups", {}, true);
    this.initialize("Connection", $.connection, true);
    this.initialize("Extend", {});
    this.Hubs = {};
    this.addHub = function (name, extend) {
        if (self.Hubs[name]) {
            return false;
        }
        self.Hubs[name] = params.Connection[name];
        self.Hubs[name].Groups = {};
        params.RawHubs.push(name);
        if (!params.RawGroups[name]) {
            params.RawGroups[name] = [];
        }
        if (extend) {
            if ((!self.Extend) || (!extend.append)) {
                self.Extend = extend;
            } else {
                if (!self.Extend) {
                    self.Extend = {};
                }
                if (extend.append) {
                    for (var extendIndex in extend) {
                        if (extendIndex !== "append") {
                            self.Extend = extend[extendIndex];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    self.Extend = extend;
                }
            }
            $.extend(params.Connection[name].client, self.Extend);
        } else if (self.Extend) {
            $.extend(params.Connection[name].client, self.Extend);
        }
        return true;
    };
    this.removeHub = function (name) {
        if (!self.Hubs[name]) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var groupIndex in self.Hubs[name].Groups) {
            self.Hubs[name].Groups[groupIndex].unsubscribe();
        }
        delete self.Hubs[name];
        delete params.RawGroups[name];
        params.RawHubs.splice(params.RawHubs.indexOf(name), 1);
        return true;
    };
    this.addGroupToHub = function (hubName, groupName) {
        if ((self.Hubs[hubName]) && (self.Hubs[hubName].Groups[groupName])) {
            return false;
        }
        self.Hubs[hubName].server.subscribe(groupName);
        self.Hubs[hubName].Groups[groupName] = {}; //Here we can hold group-related data
        if (params.RawGroups[hubName].indexOf(groupName) < 0) {
            params.RawGroups[hubName].push(groupName);
        }
        return true;
    };
    this.removeGroupFromHub = function (hubName, groupName) {
        if ((!self.Hubs[hubName]) || (!self.Hubs[hubName].Groups[groupName])) {
            return false;
        }
        self.Hubs[hubName].server.unsubscribe(groupName);
        delete self.Hubs[hubName].Groups[groupName];
        if (params.RawGroups[hubName].indexOf(groupName) >= 0) {
            params.RawGroups[hubName].splice(params.RawGroups[hubName].indexOf(groupName), 1);
        }
        return true;
    };
    for (var hubIndex in params.RawHubs) {
        self.addHub(params.RawHubs[hubIndex]);
    }
    params.Connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        for (var hubIndex in params.RawGroups) {
            for (var groupIndex in params.RawGroups[hubIndex]) {
                self.addGroupToHub(hubIndex, params.RawGroups[hubIndex][groupIndex]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am using it like this, for example:

```
    function statusUpdate(status) {
        alert(status);
    }
    var signalRUpdater = new SignalRUpdater({
        RawHubs: ["statusUpdates"],
        Extend: {
            statusUpdate: statusUpdate
        }
    });
```

So far, so good. However, I may have several groups in the same hub and at the point of `statusUpdate` I do not seem to know about the group. I can send it from server-side as a parameter to `statusUpdate`, but I wonder whether this is an overkill and whether it is possible out of the box with SignalR.

Comment: If you are asking if the server sends information what group the message was sent to along with the message then the answer is no - the server selects clients that are members of the group the message is targeted to and just send them the message.

Comment: @Pawel, yes, I was asking that. Your comment is good for an answer. If you convert it into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a group message to clients the server does not send the name of the group the message was sent to. The server selects clients that are members of the group and just sends them the message. If you want to understand the protocol SignalR is using you can find a description I wrote some time ago [here](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/).